# Getting a warning message while following the official documentation of react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, tabbar

I am currently working on implementing the Tab feature of React Navigation and I have encountered a warning message when I try to define the Tab.Navigator component according to the official documentation. In order to customize the tabBarIcon, I followed the code example provided in the documentation:

```js
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const BottomTabScreen = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({route}) => ({
        tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true,
        tabBarShowLabel: false,
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarStyle: {
          height: 70,
        },
        tabBarIcon: ({focused, size, color}) => {
          let iconName;
          if (route.name === 'Home') {
            iconName = focused ? 'home-sharp' : 'home-outline';
          } else if (route.name === 'Search') {
            iconName = focused ? 'search' : 'ios-search-outline';
          } else if (route.name === 'Activity') {
            iconName = focused ? 'ios-heart' : 'ios-heart-outline';
          } else if (route.name === 'Profile') {
            iconName = focused ? 'ios-person-circle' : 'ios-person-outline';
            size = focused ? size + 3 : size;
          }
          return <Ionic name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
        },
      })}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={Search} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Activity" component={Activity} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

However, I am receiving the following warning message:

> "Do not define components during render. React will see a new
> component type on every render and destroy the entire subtree’s DOM
> nodes and state."

I would like to know if there is a way to resolve this warning message. I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance on this matter. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the component definition outside of the navigator:

```js
// moved
const TabIcon = ({focused, size, color}) => {
          let iconName;
          if (route.name === 'Home') {
            iconName = focused ? 'home-sharp' : 'home-outline';
          } else if (route.name === 'Search') {
            iconName = focused ? 'search' : 'ios-search-outline';
          } else if (route.name === 'Activity') {
            iconName = focused ? 'ios-heart' : 'ios-heart-outline';
          } else if (route.name === 'Profile') {
            iconName = focused ? 'ios-person-circle' : 'ios-person-outline';
            size = focused ? size + 3 : size;
          }
          return <Ionic name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
};

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const BottomTabScreen = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({route}) => ({
        tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true,
        tabBarShowLabel: false,
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarStyle: {
          height: 70,
        },
        tabBarIcon: (props) => <TabIcon {...props} />, // new
      })}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={Search} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Activity" component={Activity} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide an answer to my question. I really appreciate it !

Comment: Does this actually improve something or is it just to keep `eslint` quiet? What difference does this make?

Comment: The error message is helpful: "React will see a new component type on every render and destroy the entire subtree’s DOM nodes and state". In the body, the component is recreated every render.